# how to convert object to valid css styles in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have an object and need to convert it into css, ex:

```json
     const options = {
            style: {
                base: {
                    background: 'red',
                    ':hover': {
                        background: 'green',
                    },
                },
            },
        };
```

i used package [jso-to-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-css) works fine but in case nested object like hover return `[Object]`

```
base{background:red;:hover:[object Object]}
```

instead of

```
base{background:red;}
base:hover{background: green;}
```

also, any suggestion compatible with react is welcomed.

Comment: There is no JSON in the question, so I changed the it to "object" as that is what it is.

Comment: Try to wrap the keys in quotes as well.
`background: 'red'` -> `'background': 'red'`

Comment: But your expected output like `action{background:red;:hover:{color: '#fff'}}` is no valid CSS

Comment: yes, i updated the question and made it simple, the goal is to convert this `json, object, variable, etc..` into valid css to be passed into react component.

Answer (score 0):

If you change yor data structure - you can create style rules easily frm an object or JSON etc.

Knowing the anatomy of a style rule has three parts - **selector** / **property** and **value** - you can create a data structure to allow for these to be parsed into strings and then inserted  either into an existing style sheet  - or you can create an entirely new stylesheet, append it to the document head and then insert the rules.

You will need to create a plan to allow the code to know about nesting - for example - I am using pseudostates as a child array to allow the styling of the base element - and iterate over the pseudostates array and for each - pass it to the same createStyle function as the original base element, and create their style rules... you can do this to any depth and with any type of styling - you jsut need to plan for it and update the structure of the data to match the planned styling.

In the following - i am setting the background color and text color of the p element and then changing both on the hover. You could extend this to have the type of selector (id or class) - but will leave that for further development. This includes the "#" or the "." in the selector.

```js
const options = [{
  selector: '.base',
  declarations: [{
    property: 'background',
    value: 'red',
   },{
    property: 'color',
    value: 'white',
   }],
  pseudoStates:[{
    selector: ':hover',
    declarations: [{
      property: 'background',
      value: 'green'
     },{
      property: 'color',
      value: 'orange'
     },{
      property: 'cursor',
      value: 'pointer'
     }]
  }]
}, {
  selector: '#extra',
  declarations: [{
    property: 'background',
    value: 'aqua',
   },{
    property: 'color',
    value: 'black',
   }],
  pseudoStates:[{
    selector: ':hover',
    declarations: [{
      property: 'background',
      value: 'blue'
     },{
      property: 'color',
      value: 'white'
     }]
  }]
}]

options.forEach(function(option){
 createStyleRule(option.selector, option.declarations);
 option.pseudoStates.forEach(function(pS){
   createStyleRule(option.selector + pS.selector, pS.declarations);
 })
});

function createStyleRule(selector, declarations){
  let styleDeclarations = [];
  declarations.forEach(function(dec){
    styleDeclarations.push( dec.property +": " + dec.value);
  })
  let styleRule = selector + " {" + styleDeclarations.join("; ") + "}";
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(styleRule, 0);
}
```

```html
<p class="base">This is the base element</p>
<p id="extra">This is the extra element</p>
```

Comment: you are right, that makes sense but actually, I need the end user to pass this `option` as he knows CSS not forcing him to follow my customizable solution nevertheless I can also force him to pass all as a valid JSON or string as @Jerry Ben mentioned then parse it and making my life easier.